# Azure Devops: How to retrieve Service Connection authentication token

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to retrieve a github service connection access token which then I can use later on in my script.

I am calling the endpoint to get the connection from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/get-service-endpoints?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=7.0
```

this returns the service connection correctly, but the authentication property only has the schema field inside. The docs show it also having a parameters field which should hold my token.

```
...
"authorization": {
        "scheme": "Token"
      },
...
```

I tried setting the `Project Collection Build Service (account):` and the `(Project) Build service (account)` permissions with admin access. This did help as before I did not get the service connection at all, but I am still missing what I need from it.

Comment: Why are you trying to extract the access token from the GitHub Service Connection, can you not set it as a masked pipeline variable or in the variable group? and then use it in your script

Comment: @Sibtain I do not know what this access token is at all, it is just used by github operations in pipelines.  My goal is to use the existing github access token which the service connection has, instead of creating a separate github token and saving in in pipeline vars.

Comment: The API will never just return the token, for security purposes you can only set it using the REST API. Only an executing pipeline will get access to the token through its evironment. If you want to use an existing token, you need to create a custom task that has an input of the correct service endpoint type.

Comment: Service Endpoint API doesn't return the value where the Service Connection has a "secret", just like you have an access token in your GitHub SC.